How many Carats is 1 gold piece in DND?
I need to find out how much 1 gold piece is, for something I'm doing in a rp thing

Related: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/107753/39969

@ThomasMarkov sorry, I was just specifying which edition the gold is from, since gold is worth different amounts in different editions, and the character is from 5e, so I was trying to ensure that we all know what gold we're talking about

I agree with Tasi; D&D gold coins are not always consistent from one edition to the next, so if the answer depends on the particular physical dimensions of the coin from a particular edition, the question should have that edition’s tag.

I have restored the edition tag as the querent has clarified exactly which edition they're playing and that information may be relevant to useful answers.

Voting to close as unclear:  Is the OP asking about mass (carat, but typically used for diamonds) or purity (karat, different spelling but typically used for gold)?

@Novak when I was asked this question on reddit it was spelled with a c, not a k, so probably the first one

It would still be helpful if you could determine which it is that you're looking for. Don't trust someone else's [mis]spelling of the term :) What is it you are trying to figure out?

I try to be as tolerant of ambiguity as I can, and VTC as infrequently as I can, but I do think the person asking the question should know and be able to clarify what they're asking about.

According to the (2014) Players Handbook, 50 gold coins weight 1 lb. There are 2268 Carats in one pound, so 1/50 lb is 45.3 Carats.
I don't believe anywhere mentions the purity of these coins, but Wikipedia claims that most modern gold circulation coins were 22-karat (which comes out to ~90% pure). This would give us 40.8 Carats of pure gold in a single gold piece.

+1, though I must comment that whether or not modern standards of purity are appropriate to D&D gold coins is extremely debatable—after all, they have magic but don’t have modern chemical theory (for that matter, modern real-world chemical theory may not even apply in D&D). The purity could easily be lower (as they were historically, in reality) or higher (using magic both to purify and to strengthen the coin).

If it's relevant, that much gold is worth over USD 1000 today. See https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/61840/how-much-is-a-gold-piece-really-worth/61870

Also, a carat wrt to gold is a measure of purity not mass like it is for gemstones.

Not to mention that electrum was a common form of coinage in certain Roman Imperial phases, a mix of silver and gold ... and taking the very common debasing of currency that went on...some assumptions need to be made as regards purity.  This answers assumption is sufficient for game play.

Impossible to say
First, another answer has suggested that 1 carat = 200 mg, which it does if you are talking about diamonds, but not if you are talking about gold. Carats are a measure of mass in diamonds, but a measure of purity in gold. To avoid confusion, some people use the alternate spelling karat for gold and carat for diamonds.
As incorrect as it is to use a carat as a unit of weight for gold, that answer is correct for D&D 5e based on the assumption of 90% of the mass being gold (approx. 22 karat). However, gp have not had a consistent weight across all editions. Sometimes, they have been 50 to the pound and sometimes 10 to the pound. So if you were going to weigh your gp in carats, which you definitely shouldn't, the answer of 45.3 carats is only correct for 1/50 lb gp; for 1/10 lb gp it's 226.5.
Now, if you are using carat (or karat) correctly to mean purity, then 24 karat gold is 100% pure, and each karat less reduces the purity by 4 4/24 %. So, all you need to do is work out how much of the gp is actual gold and multiply that by 24 and Bob's your uncle.
Except, you can't. See How much is a Gold Piece really worth? We simply don't know how much gold there is in a gold piece, and have no realistic way of determining it.
However, we can make educated guesses.
Modern gold coins (c. 1800-1933) used in circulation were around 22-karat. Ceremonial bullion coins, not intended for circulation, are typically pure gold or 24-karat.
Before the modern era, the purity of coins (gold and silver) was … variable. Counterfeiting aside, there was always an incentive on the maker (a ruler of some kind) to adulterate their coinage - less precious metal in the coins means more coins. But, adulterated coinage is untrustworthy coinage which defeats the entire reason for making them: facilitating trade by making a trustworthy money. When you are dealing with commodity money rather than fiat money, that’s a real problem.
Electrum coins exist in D&D, and also historically. Naturally occurring electrum can be anywhere from 20-80% gold (5-19 karat). This explains why in the 2ep = 1gp, its got about half as much gold.
So, probably no less than 20 karat; unless they’re badly adulterated.
